# Google.com autocomplete feature in Google Chrome omninox

Tags: google-chrome

Under the manage search engines section in preferences, I deleted the original Google search engine and added a new one with the same "URL" string. When I type in the Omnibar, search works fine however it fails to autocomplete the word. How should I remedy this?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, there's no way to manually restore the default Google search with all its features.<sup>1</sup>

However, you *can* delete the configuration file that contains user-defined searches and let Chrome recreate it.

#### Steps

1. Close Chrome.
2. Locate your profile's Chrome folder.

   Windows 8, 7 and Vista:

   ```
   %LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default
   ```

   Windows XP:

   ```
   %USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default
   ```

   Linux:

   ```
   ~/.config/google-chrome/Default
   ```

   Mac OS X:

   ```
   ~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default
   ```

   If you're not using the default profile, replace `Default` with your profile name.
3. Move the files *Web Data* and *Web Data-journal* elsewhere, so you can restore them in case their absence causes unexpected problems.
4. Reopen Chrome. If you use a Google Account, sign in.
5. Select the restored default Google search in *Manage search engines* and make sure the option *Enable Instant for faster searching* is checked.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> The default Google search doesn't appear in the *Web Data* like user-defined searches. Selecting the default search modifies the properties `"instant_url"` and `"suggest_url"` of `"default_search_provider"` in the *Preferences* file. Even modifying those properties manually doesn't have the desired effect, since Chrome removes them on restart.</sub>